# Understanding the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: ruby, fibonacci

I have an algorithm that I found online that calculates the Fibonacci sequence. I feel a bit like a fool but I have no idea how it works!

```
 def fib(n)

  if n == 0 || n == 1
   return n
  end

  if n >= 2
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
  end
 end
```

If I call the method with the argument of 10 why does it not return 18? I assume some recursion is happening here but I have no idea. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: What does it return when you call it with 10? Why do you want 18? The tenth Fibonacci number is 55.

Comment: yes it is recursion. [here](http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-programming/recursion) is a good tutorial which covers recursive fibonacci

Comment: Maybe because 18 is not a Fibonacci number?! The code you posted seems correct.

Comment: It's horribly inefficient algorithm, btw :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at `fib(4)`, according to your code above:

```
fib(4) #=> 3
```

It does so by using the following results:

```
fib(4) #calculates fib(3) + fib(2)
fib(3) #calculates fib(2) + fib(1)
fib(2) #calculates fib(1) + fib(0)
fib(1) #returns 1
fib(0) #returns 0
```

Crudely speaking your method uses the above results in the following fashion
(*note: below I am using math-notation (not code)* and some dubious spacing to illustrate which bits are being substituted with the results from above):

```
# fib(4) =   fib(3)                       +  fib(2)
#        = ( fib(2)            + fib(1))  + (fib(1) + fib(0))
#        = ((fib(1) + fib(0))  + 1     )  + (1      + 0     )
#        = ((1      + 0     )  + 1     )  +  1
#        = ( 1                 + 1     )  +  1
#        =   2                            +  1
#        =   3
```

Your algorithm goes through the above steps. Similarly for `fib(10)`, although it's hardly worth going through it manually as it can be quite cumbersome. As long as you get the basic idea, move on. And by the way you're not a fool, you're just trying to get better at something which is what many of us are trying to do as well. Good luck.