# Ruby Fibonacci Example

Tags: ruby

```
class Fibonacci
  def calc(n)
    return n if n < 2
    return calc(n - 1) + calc(n - 2)
  end
end

puts Fibonacci.new.calc(40)
>> 102334155
```

I am trying to make sense of this program. I understand it is recursively calling the calc method twice if it is not 0 or 1, but I don't understand how it is working to get the correct number for the sequence.

I know this is my inexperience showing, but can someone explain to me how this is calculating the fib sequence correctly? It's just not clicking for me.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you clarify? Do you know what a Fibonacci number is? Do you know how it is (usually) defined? Do you understand the definition? Do you know how to compute a Fibonacci number by hand, with pen and paper? Have you tried it? Have you tried executing the code by hand with pen and paper? Oh, and BTW: "can someone explain to me how this is calculating the fib sequence correctly?" – It isn't computing the Fibonacci Sequence, it is computing the `n`_th number of the Fibonacci Sequence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the Fibonacci sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580523/understanding-the-fibonacci-sequence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are having trouble understanding what code is doing, you may have to resort to salting it with `puts` statements. For recursions it's also helpful to vary indentation to show when a method calls itself and when a method returns. Here is one way you might do that for your code.

```
INDENT = 4
@tabs = 0

def calc(n)
  pr_indent
  puts "entered calc(#{n})"
  if n < 2
    pr_indent
    puts "returning n=#{n}"
    @tabs -= 1
    return n
  end
  pr_indent
  puts "calling calc(#{n-1})"
  @tabs += 1
  m1 = calc(n-1)
  pr_indent
  puts "calc(#{n-1}) returned m1=#{m1} to calc(#{n})"
  pr_indent
  puts "calling calc(#{n-2})"
  @tabs += 1
  m2 = calc(n-2)
  pr_indent
  puts "calc(#{n-2}) returned m2=#{m2} to calc(#{n-1})"
  pr_indent
  puts "returning m1+m2=#{m1+m2}"
  @tabs -= 1
  m1+m2
end

def pr_indent
  print "#{' '*(@tabs*INDENT)}"
end
```

Now execute

```
calc(4)
```

causing the following to be printed. I will not provide running comments at it should be self-explanatory when you read what is printed as you step through the code.

```
entered calc(4)
calling calc(3)
    entered calc(3)
    calling calc(2)
        entered calc(2)
        calling calc(1)
            entered calc(1)
            returning n=1
        calc(1) returned m1=1 to calc(2)
        calling calc(0)
            entered calc(0)
            returning n=0
        calc(0) returned m2=0 to calc(1)
        returning m1+m2=1
    calc(2) returned m1=1 to calc(3)
    calling calc(1)
        entered calc(1)
        returning n=1
    calc(1) returned m2=1 to calc(2)
    returning m1+m2=2
calc(3) returned m1=2 to calc(4)
calling calc(2)
    entered calc(2)
    calling calc(1)
        entered calc(1)
        returning n=1
    calc(1) returned m1=1 to calc(2)
    calling calc(0)
        entered calc(0)
        returning n=0
    calc(0) returned m2=0 to calc(1)
    returning m1+m2=1
calc(2) returned m2=1 to calc(3)
returning m1+m2=3
```

and `calc(4)` returns `3`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's use `n == 3` as an example:

First iteration: `n` is not `0` or `1`, so the guard clause won't be true. So we'll calculate `calc(2) + calc(1)`.

Call to `calc(2)`: We call `calc(1) + calc(0)`. Both of these satisfy the guard clause, so `1` and `0` get returned respectively. So the result for this computation is `1`.

Call to `calc(1)`: The guard clause triggers and `1` gets returned.

We now add up the two `1`s and get the correct result, `2`.

Try to apply the same reasoning for a higher value of `n` and keep in mind that this implementation is extremely wasteful, since it will repeatedly calculate the same values.