# How this Fibonacci code(Ruby) works?

Tags: ruby, recursion, fibonacci

I understood how the formula for Fibonacci works but not the recursion part.
For example, fib(4) will call for fib(3) + fib(2), then what? How does the method determines the value of fib(3) and fib(2)? I am a beginner in Ruby so please excuse me for asking a noob question.

```
def fib num
    return num if(0..1).include? num
    fib(num-1) + fib(num-2)
end
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with fibonacci or ruby. You are having a problem with recursion... and how recursion works has been asked and answered a hundred times already.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580523/understanding-the-fibonacci-sequence/38582180#38582180

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion works by calling itself again and again until the 'break point' happens.
Fib(4) calls for fib(3) and fib(2), fib(3) calls for fib(2) and fib(1)... method has given the value of fib(1) and fib(0) as 1.

Let me try to explain it visually:

```
> fib(4) =         fib(3)                 +            fib(2) 
> =>       fib(2)        +   fib(1)       +        fib(1)  +  fib(0)
> =>   fib(1) + fib(0)   +   1            +          1     +   1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do deep study here some links

https://www.dotnetperls.com/fibonacci-ruby

http://www.mattmorgante.com/technology/algorithms